# How to get the element in Vector using the specified position in c++?

Tags: c++, stl

How to get the element by providing position in vector template?

Comment: What reference material for vectors are you using that didn't explain that within the first two paragraphs? Consider using something else.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You access std::vector elements just like a regular C array:

```
std::vector<int> myVector;

//(...)


int a = myVector[1];
```

Answer (score 18):

You could use the 'at' function (someVector.at(somePosition) gets you the element at somePosition), or you could use someVector[somePosition]. It's like a more developed array.

The difference between using the at function is that it will throw an exception if you give it an invalid position, while the []s don't check for things like that.

Comment: The implementations of std::vector that I use check.  An out of bounds access results in basically the same behavior as an assertion failure, which in many cases, is far preferable to the exception.

Answer (score 7):

There are 2 ways to accomplish what you want (for a vector say Vec):

```
  (1) Use at() function eg. Vec.at(index)

  (2) Use like a normal array eg. Vec[index]
```

Answer (score 1):

Indexing works on Vectors, So just Acces it by using index. Similar to arrays.